# Scraping only the number inside a string

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I got elements like this:

```
<span class="narrowValue">&nbsp;(15,728)</span>
```

Which I'm scraping like this:

```
  @department_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}
  department.css('.narrowValue').each do | department |
    @department_hash["department"] << department.text
  end
```

And get results like this:

```
{"department"=>[" (15,725)", " (243,256)", " (510,337)", " (46,002)", " (14,109)", " (358)", " (5,787)", " (19,818)"]}
```

But I don't need the parenthesis.

How can I do it to only get the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@department_hash["department"] << department.text[/[\d,]+/]
```

Comment: Yes. You don't need gsub.

Answer (score 1):

Before push a text to the array, strip parenthesis.

```
@department_hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}
department.css('.narrowValue').each do | department |
  @department_hash["department"] << department.text.gsub(/^[() \u00a0]+|[() \u00a0]+$/, '')
end
```

Alternatively you can use following regular expression:

```
/^[()[:space:]]+|[()[:space:]]+$/
```

`[[:space:]]` matches nbsp, but `\s` does not match nbsp.

Comment: Strange, I tried that and only one parenthesis was removed (the first one).

Comment: @alexchenco, Did you use `String#sub` instead of `String#gsub`?

Comment: Nope. Strange. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: @alexchenco, Where can I get the html?

Comment: here's the HTML: http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dpets&field-keywords=

Comment: @alexchenco, It was NBSP, or Non-breaking space (`U+00A0`). I updated the answer to handle nbsp.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following modification:

```
@department_hash["department"] << department.text.gsub(/[^\d,]/,"")
```